# Why flexbox is moving left when i resize the window

Tags: css, flexbox

when i resize the window the header moves to the left. And the flexbox dont stay in the center.And sorry im new to stackoverflow so i forgive my mistakes.[see this image for a better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaAXu.png)

(Please skip this text cause stackoverflow is blocking my post jdjdjd sksjdhd sisjjdjd didjjd sidjf sijdjd sidjjd idjdjd idjdjjd)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Md Hasan</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header-left">
        <a href="#"
          ><img
            class="logo"
            src="gallery/received_344045126587298.jpeg"
            width="100px"
            height="70px"
            alt="logo"
          />
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <h1>Md Hasan</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <section id="about">
        <div class="aboutText">
          <div class="f1">
            <h1>Who Is Hasan</h1>
            <p>
              Hasan is a Business man. He runs a Rubber Factory. He is a Good
              person with a kind Heart. This website is just a gift for him
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="f2">
            <a
              href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/100011445344575"
              target="_blank"
              ><button id="btn" onmouseout="btnf()" onmouseover="btnfuc()">
                DM Hasan on FB
              </button></a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="aboutImg">
          <img src="gallery/hasan.jpg" alt="About Hasan" class="aboutImg" />
        </div>
      </section>
      <hr />
      <section id="gallery">
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <p>Here you can see some rare pictures of Living Legend Md Hasan</p>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="gallery/IMG20180305171539.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="gallery/IMG20180616172814.jpg" alt="" />
          <img class="im3" src="gallery/IMG_20190404_201412.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </section>
      <hr />
      <section id="contact">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <p>
          <i>Need Hasan's Facebook Id? ok here you go.</i>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011445344575">
            <img
              class="fbLogo"
              src="gallery/Facebook-logo-768x538.png"
              alt="fb-link"
            />
            Md Hasan
          </a>
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <em class="em1"
        >Created by - Ahmed Rafin | I'm a professional. Please give me Job.</em
      >
      <em class="em2">
        <a href="https://facebook.com/psycho.rafin"
          >Contact Me on
          <img
            class="fbLogo"
            src="gallery/Facebook-logo-768x538.png"
            alt="" /></a
      ></em>
    </footer>
    <script>
      btnfuc = () => {
        console.log('button hovered');
        document.getElementById('btn').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      };
      btnf = () => {
        document.getElementById('btn').style.backgroundColor = 'blueviolet';
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

now this is the css part . you can  check this . and again sorry if my mistakes guys

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Header section start from here */

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: auto;
}

header .header-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
header .logo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.header-left a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
header a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.header-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-right a {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.header-right a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

/* Header section end */

/* Container and after that about hasan section */

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
#about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 25px;
}
.aboutText {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section .aboutImg {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
section .aboutText {
  width: 50%;
}
#about h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#about p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}
#about button {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: rgb(61, 61, 230);
  margin: 25px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* About section end  */

/* Gallery section starts */

#gallery h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

#gallery p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

section .flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex img {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.flex img:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

/* Gallery section end  */

/* Contact us page  */

#contact h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

#contact p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

#contact img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
}

#contact a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(70, 21, 21);
}
#contact a:hover {
  color: green;
}

/* now the last foooter area */

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
}

footer em {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
}
footer img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:hover {
  color: green;
}

/* end for computers and now media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To Why flexbox is moving left when i resize the window

```css
html {
  background-color: #141E30;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #0a0c0f;
  color: #EAE9E9;
}

.sidebar__profile {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar__menuitem {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

.count {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background-color: #EAE9E9;
  color: #0a0c0f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div>
        <div class="sidebar__profile">
          <img src="http://chittagongit.com//images/avatar-icon/avatar-icon-4.jpg" height=50px alt="image" class="sidebar__profile__avatar" />
          <div class="sidebar__profile__name">User Name</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 1</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 2</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 3</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 4</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 5</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 6</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 7</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code.  What exactly is the problem? looks good from here.

```js
      btnfuc = () => {
        
        document.getElementById('btn').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      };
      btnf = () => {
        document.getElementById('btn').style.backgroundColor = 'blueviolet';
      };
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Header section start from here */

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: auto;
}

header .header-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
header .logo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.header-left a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
header a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.header-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-right a {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.header-right a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

/* Header section end */

/* Container and after that about hasan section */

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
#about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 25px;
}
.aboutText {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section .aboutImg {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
section .aboutText {
  width: 50%;
}
#about h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#about p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}
#about button {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: rgb(61, 61, 230);
  margin: 25px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* About section end  */

/* Gallery section starts */

#gallery h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

#gallery p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

section .flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex img {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.flex img:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

/* Gallery section end  */

/* Contact us page  */

#contact h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

#contact p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

#contact img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
}

#contact a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(70, 21, 21);
}
#contact a:hover {
  color: green;
}

/* now the last foooter area */

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
}

footer em {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
}
footer img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:hover {
  color: green;
}

/* end for computers and now media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Md Hasan</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header-left">
        <a href="#"
          ><img
            class="logo"
            src="gallery/received_344045126587298.jpeg"
            width="100px"
            height="70px"
            alt="logo"
          />
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <h1>Md Hasan</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <section id="about">
        <div class="aboutText">
          <div class="f1">
            <h1>Who Is Hasan</h1>
            <p>
              Hasan is a Business man. He runs a Rubber Factory. He is a Good
              person with a kind Heart. This website is just a gift for him
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="f2">
            <a
              href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/100011445344575"
              target="_blank"
              ><button id="btn" onmouseout="btnf()" onmouseover="btnfuc()">
                DM Hasan on FB
              </button></a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="aboutImg">
          <img src="gallery/hasan.jpg" alt="About Hasan" class="aboutImg" />
        </div>
      </section>
      <hr />
      <section id="gallery">
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <p>Here you can see some rare pictures of Living Legend Md Hasan</p>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="gallery/IMG20180305171539.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="gallery/IMG20180616172814.jpg" alt="" />
          <img class="im3" src="gallery/IMG_20190404_201412.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </section>
      <hr />
      <section id="contact">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <p>
          <i>Need Hasan's Facebook Id? ok here you go.</i>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011445344575">
            <img
              class="fbLogo"
              src="gallery/Facebook-logo-768x538.png"
              alt="fb-link"
            />
            Md Hasan
          </a>
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <em class="em1"
        >Created by - Ahmed Rafin | I'm a professional. Please give me Job.</em
      >
      <em class="em2">
        <a href="https://facebook.com/psycho.rafin"
          >Contact Me on
          <img
            class="fbLogo"
            src="gallery/Facebook-logo-768x538.png"
            alt="" /></a
      ></em>
    </footer>
    
  </body>
</html>
```